# Is there any PDF software for Windows which can print the target page number in the margin opposite a link?

Tags: pdf, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor, pdf-generation

If you have a link in a PDF which points to a page within the same document, is there any easy way to get the number of the page pointed to to appear in the right hand margin opposite the link, so that someone using a hardcopy can see which page the link points to?

I am looking for software which works on Windows priced at less than 500 British pounds (approx 700 US dollars).

Comment: Hi Nemo.  Do you have any price range preference, or are you looking for recommendations for gratis software?  Also, any OS preference?  If you will, please update your question with answers to these questions.  Thanks, and again, welcome!

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket Good point. I have edited it now.

Comment: Looks good Nemo.  Any OS preference(s)?

Comment: Windows. I have added that in now.